# Loop to save and close each open email leaves one open

Tags: vba, outlook

I often have many windows open and it becomes tedious to close Outlook.

I've written two versions of this QuickClose procedure, they tend to leave an email open.

This one throws an index array out of bounds error:

```
Sub QuickClose()

Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim InspectorCount, i As Integer
Dim myItem As Object
'On Error Resume Next
If Application.Inspectors.count > 0 Then
    InspectorCount = Application.Inspectors.count

    For i = 1 To InspectorCount
        Set myItem = Application.Inspectors.Item(i)

        myItem.Activate

        If TypeName(myItem) = "Message" Then

            myItem.Close olSave

        End If

        If TypeOf ActiveInspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then

            ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Close olSave

        End If

    Next i

End If

End Sub
```

No errors from this one, but it also tends to leave an email open (and not saved):

```
Sub QuickClose1()

Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim InspectorCount As Integer
Dim myItem As Object

If Application.Inspectors.count > 0 Then

    For Each Inspector In Application.Inspectors
        Inspector.Activate
        Inspector.CurrentItem.Close olSave
    Next Inspector

End If
End Sub
```

Once I get this section working, it will go on to close Outlook.

Comment: You can close all Outlook (Office desktop) windows by adding the button to the QAT (quick access toolbar). Search for the Exit button. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137409/for-each-loop-not-deleting-all-items and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391257/trying-to-move-emails-in-a-loop-but-not-all-get-moved-in-the-first-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to get an item from the active inspector window. You can use the [Inspector.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.close(method)) method which closes the `Inspector` and optionally saves changes to the displayed Outlook item.

```
Sub QuickClose()

Dim inspectors As Outlook.inspectors
Dim inspector As Outlook.inspector

Set inspectors = Application.inspectors

Do While inspectors.Count > 0
  Set inspector = inspectors.Item(1)
  inspector.Close olSave
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Iterating a collection with for each  and removeing items from it causes confuson, as item position in collection changes and decreases,what for each is not aware of. E.g if first item is deleted,, former second is now first former third is now second, but for each continues with second element!. Use LBound/Ubound and step reverse to delete the last item, what don''t causes a new item position!

Comment: Thank you @ComputerVersteher. I have corrected the code.